# consuming REST API (DRF)

Tags: django-rest-framework

I need to access the detail of the object referenced by the the shown URL in the JSON data below, how would do that say in a frontend? The relationship is made using HyperlinkedModelSerializer

{
    "id": 1,
    "item": "http://localhost:8000/api/mine/2/"
}

Comment: Can you describe in more details what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to load an image which is referenced by that url instead of its primary key, so that when you click on the link in this question it takes you to the details of that image which looks like this { "id": 2, "photo": "http://localhost:8000/api/images/img.png", "author":"kim" }. My question would be how will I access "photo" in my frontend.  I tried; {item.photo}  doesn't work

Comment: If you're displaying it you can use <img> tag where src will be photo's url

Comment: First of all you need to get this details from ../mine/2 URL. What function do you use to make request to that endpoint ?

Comment: axios.get('/api/sel/') when i use that the json data is this { "id": 1, "item": "http://localhost:8000/api/mine/2/" } which comes as expected, but now what i want to display is referenced by the url, such that when you click on this json data url it will take you to the object i need, it is not a nested serializer,  rather the relationship is the link

Comment: Then you need to request item like axios.get('localhost:8000/api/mine/2') and you will get response. Assuming that you assign your response to variable named "response" then you can access img url like this: response.photo. I dont understand what you want to achieve. I guess you dont know how to access this json response. Try this: 

let respone;
axios.get('/api/sel/').then(res => response = res)
axios.get(response.item).then(res => console.log(res.photo))

Comment: thanks, I will try this. I used a nested serializer which seemed to work fine.   {
        "id": 1,
        "item": {
            "id": 3
            "date_posted": "2020-05-07T05:46:23.219326Z",
            "img_file": "/media/images/img.png
        }
    },

Comment: instead of using the nested serializer as pointed out in the question i wanted to user the hyperlinkedmodelserializer which gives the URL of "item" which upon clicking takes you to the object with these details  { "id": 3 "date_posted": "2020-05-07T05:46:23.219326Z", "img_file": "/media/images/img.png }